# batch script to delete files with todays date in the name

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I have a legacy job that creates a file like this `am_mailplan.xlsx_20200228_090901AM`

I need to check if the file exists in that path and if yes just write to a log. But that folder also has older files. so i need to check if part of the file name contains todays date in it. So I tried the below code and it is able to find files with the todays date in its name and writing to log as expected.

After this the last step is to delete that files which has today's date in its name. There could be multiple files from today. So I am using del "%FileName%*", when i run the bat file, it is deleting previously present files but it is creating a new file again. For example it is if i run the bat file at 11:45, any files before that are deleted `am_mailplan.xlsx_20200309_105446AM` and a new file at 11:05 is created `am_mailplan.xlsx_20200309_114546AM` 
I dont see how its creating a new file, because a new file only gets created in the line where i am calling

```
start /WAIT F:\CPTS\AMMailPlan\apps\AltMediaLoad\setup.exe /s /w
```

And I am calling delete all the way at the end of the script

Please suggest a way to handle this last step of deletion

```
Rem AltMedia starts here
Rem Check if any file came for processing on the day of execution
if exist F:\CPTS\AMMailPlan\Inbound\*.txt (
    move F:\CPTS\AMMailPlan\Inbound\*.txt C:\Backup\AltMedia
    echo %DATE% %TIME% Altmedia text file moved to backup >>C:\JobValidationLog\JobValidationLog.txt
)
if exist F:\CPTS\AMMailPlan\Inbound\*.xlsx (
    move F:\CPTS\AMMailPlan\Inbound\*.xlsx  C:\Backup\AltMedia
    echo %DATE% %TIME% Altmedia xlsx file moved to backup >>C:\JobValidationLog\JobValidationLog.txt
)
Rem copy the files from test folder to inbound
xcopy H:\TestFiles\AltMediaTestFile\*.txt  F:\CPTS\AMMailPlan\Inbound
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
    echo %DATE% %TIME% AltMedia test file copied to inbound >>C:\JobValidationLog\JobValidationLog.txt
)
xcopy H:\TestFiles\AltMediaTestFile\*.xlsx  F:\CPTS\AMMailPlan\Inbound
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
    echo %DATE% %TIME% AltMedia xls test file copied to inbound >>C:\JobValidationLog\JobValidationLog.txt
)
Rem Call the load altmedia exe
start /WAIT F:\CPTS\AMMailPlan\apps\AltMediaLoad\setup.exe /s /w
echo %DATE% %TIME% Calling AltMediaLoad\setup.exe >>C:\JobValidationLog\JobValidationLog.txt

set mydate=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%
echo my date %mydate%
set "FileName=F:\CPTS\AMMailPlan\Completed\am_mailplan.xlsx_%mydate%"
if exist "%FileName%*" (
    echo %DATE% %TIME% The file exist in completed folder "%FileName%">>C:\JobValidationLog\JobValidationLog.txt
) 
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
    echo %DATE% %TIME% validation successful>>C:\JobValidationLog\JobValidationLog.txt
)
echo "%FileName%*"
del "%FileName%*"
```

Comment: The file gets created after your delete?

Comment: right James, thats what am confused, how its creating it again. Delete is the last action i am doing

Comment: I have reformatted your posted code as it was invalid. I also included indentation to assist with the readability of that code. _If your actual code matches what you originally posted, please change it to my edited version, before seeking any further assistance._

Comment: Depending on what your program does, it could be still running even though you wanted to wait. You might want to run tasklist or check that otherwise.